# replace capture match with capture group in bash GNU sed

Tags: sed

I've looked around to find a solution to my problem in other posts listed bellow, but it looks my regex is quit different and need special care:
[How to output only captured groups with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-to-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed/47268675#47268675)
[Replace one capture group with another with GNU sed (macOS) 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865384/replace-one-capture-group-with-another-with-gnu-sed-macos-4-4)
[sed replace line with capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180355/sed-replace-line-with-capture-groups)

I'm trying to replace a regex match group in big JSON file, 
My file has mongoDB exported objects, and I'm trying to replace the objectId with the string:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"},"recordId":{"$oid":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"}}
```

So the output in the original file should look like this:
    {"_id":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313","recordId":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"}

That's the command I run in the shell:

```
sed -i 's/(?:{"\$oid":)("\w+")}/\$1/g' data.json
```

I get no error, but the file remains the same.
What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use regex to modify json, use something like jq..

Comment: what's the `$oid` value?

Comment: $oid value is a string, so when you mongoexport a collection from mongo, the _id key is exported as Object:
`"_id":{"$oid":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to make it work, the way regex works in bash is different then in [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) tester tool.

```
echo '{"$oid":"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"}' | sed 's/{"$oid":\("\w*"\)}/\1/g'
```

gives the correct output:

```
"56cad2ce0481320c111d2313"
```

I found it even better to read from stdin and output to file, instead of writing first to JSON file, then read, replace and write again.

Since I use mongoexport to export collection, replace the objectId and write the output to JSON file, my final solution looks like this:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db myDB --collection my_collection | sed 's/{"$oid":\\("\\w*"\\)}/\\1/g' >> data.json
```

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y